# How to execute a laravel queue job sequentially with supervisor?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, supervisord, laravel-queue, php-7.3

I have a job that is queued when user hits a url.

```
public function demoPR(Request $request) {
    // ...
    SavePRJob::dispatch($request->all(), $data);
}
```

And SavePRJob class

```
class SavePRJob implements ShouldQueue {
    private $inputs;
    private $data;

    public function __construct($inputs, $data) {
        $this->inputs = $inputs;
        $this->data = $data;
    }


    public function handle() {
        $inputs = $this->inputs;
        $prs = PR::whereIn('email', $input['emails'])->get();
        $bulkSave = array();
        foreach($data as $d){
            //if $d already exists in db, update it else collect data to save and bulk insert
            if($pr = $prs->firstWhere('email', $d['email'])) {
                $pr->num_t = $d['num_t'];
                //....
                $pr->save();
            } else {
                $bulkSave[] = $d;
            }
        }

        //bulk insert
        if(count($bulkSave) > 0) {
            //...
            PR::insert($bulkSave);
        }
        //...
    }

}
```

I have made supervisor configuration as given in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration). With the configuration, the job runs well. To test the behaviour with multiple users hitting the same url at the same time, I submitted the web request from 2 tabs of the web browser, say req1 and req2. Expected behaviour was that the job submitted by req1's `MyController@demoPR` will execute and then the one from req2. This was observed when I looked at the logs. Generally the job takes about 2.5 mins. But when I went through logs, the jobs were taken to execute with just a time difference of 1 sec - the same time difference I would have taken to switch through the tabs for submitting another request. This means that the jobs are not taken up sequentially.

And my requirement is to execute them sequentially, to fullfil the goal of my project.

Any solution is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not certain but setting `numprocs=1` in your supervisor configuration might give you the desired result.

Comment: @Remul Thanks. I have tried this, but still the problem occurs.

Comment: how many servers do you have ? Did you reload the supervisor after the update ? How many processes listed in `supervisorctl` ?

Comment: @Ersoy currently it is simply apache2 server on ubuntu 18.04 . Yes, I reloaded the supervisor after configuration update. I even restarted my computer for more assurance. in laravel's conf file in supervisor's folder, I tried both numprocs=1 and numprocs=8.

Comment: Also, the problem does not occur if I run php artisan queue:listen <queue_name>. So I tried this in supervisor, nut still the problem persisted.

Comment: when you disable supervisor and run queue:listen in your command line it is going to melt down one-by-one, that's the normal one. If you cancel queue:listen - activate supervisor with single process (numprocs=1) it must listen one-by-one too. What queue driver do you use ? If it is redis, then run `redis-cli` -> `client list` to see how many processes connected to your redis server. if you see multiple (excluding  cdm=`client`) then some other processes are also connected to your redis - listening that queue.

Comment: Have you tried to prioritize the queue tubes? like high,normal,low?

Comment: @Ersoy it is database driver I use. Sorry if i have not provided all the details in advance.  I attempted either command line or supervisor at a time.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about how database driver works, but if you try to switch to redis - you may try my suggestions. Good luck & Best